# How do I get line numbers with PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, text-editing

I have a simple text file:

```
$ cat food.txt
Apples
Bananas
Carrots
```

## Linux/Cygwin

And I can think of several ways to get line numbers in Linux/Cygwin:

```
$ nl food.txt
     1  Apples
     2  Bananas
     3  Carrots

$ cat -n food.txt
     1  Apples
     2  Bananas
     3  Carrots

$ less -NFX food.txt
      1 Apples
      2 Bananas
      3 Carrots
```

## PowerShell

The best I've come up with is this:

**Update 2017-11-27Mo**: (1) Slight tweak added: `Out-String -Stream` to forcibly textify those pesky objects. (2) Note: I'm looking for something that will accept PIPELINE INPUT.

```
PS C:\> function nl{$input | Out-String -Stream | Select-String '.*' | Select-Object LineNumber, Line}

PS C:\> cat .\food.txt | nl
LineNumber Line
---------- ----
         1 Apples
         2 Bananas
         3 Carrots
```

Is there a simpler way? Shorter? Something builtin with PowerShell?

Comment: `cat .\food.txt | select @{ n='LineNumber'; e='ReadCount' }, @{ n='Line'; e={$_} }`

Comment: Would just: *select-string file.txt -pattern "."* be of any use?

Comment: `cat .\food.txt | %{ "$($_.ReadCount) $_" }`

Comment: `cat .\food.txt|%{ "{0,4} {1}" -f $_.ReadCount,$_ }` building on @JosefZ but numbers right justified

Comment: Probably @LotPings is the shortest and most straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

I wrapped my line into a function you may include in one of your Powershell profiles.

```
Function nl 
{
<# .Synopsis
    Mimic Unic / Linux tool nl number lines
   .Description
    Print file content with numbered lines no original nl options supported
   .Example
     nl .\food.txt
#>
  param (
    [parameter(mandatory=$true, Position=0)][String]$FileName
  )

  process {
    If (Test-Path $FileName){
      Get-Content $FileName | ForEach{ "{0,5} {1}" -f $_.ReadCount,$_ }
    }
  }
}
```

Sample output:

```
> nl .\food.txt
    1 Apples
    2 Bananas
    3 Carrots
```

Comment: That is a nice solution. Thanks. Is there a (simple) way that could be adapted to accept pipeline input? (This is what I really want.)

Comment: @StackzOfZtuff checkout my answer

Answer (score 2):

This will do it and will work with any command that produces output:

```
$i = 1; cat food.txt | % {$i++;"$($i-1) `t $_"}
```

Here is the output:

```
1        Apples
2        Bananas
3        Carrots
```

Here is an example if with a directory listing:

```
$i = 1; dir | % {$i++;"$($i-1) `t $_"}
```

Here is the output:

```
1        backgrounds
2        boot
3        inetpub
4        PerfLogs
5        Program Files
6        Program Files (x86)
7        Riot Games
8        Users
9        Windows
10       Reflect_Install.log
```

Obviously, if you want line numbering to start at 0, then set `$i = 0`.

Comment: Or do ``$i=1; dir | % {"$($i) `t $_"; $i++}``, rather than incrementing the variable before you want to, and then subtracting one from it.